# Align content to center on small device, Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a simple Bootstrap 4 row:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 p-2">
          <img class="" src="../assets/img/Logo-small.png" alt="">
      </div>            
  </div>
```

I want that whenever I view it on small device (col-sm-12), the image should be centered, but on large device (col-md-12) it should be left aligned.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use responsive margins on the image..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 p-2">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mx-md-0" src="//placehold.it/200" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/U63JXeFRrE

Or, responsive text align on the col...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center text-md-left p-2">
            <img class="" src="//placehold.it/200" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/U63JXeFRrE

Read about the Bootstrap util classes:
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities

Answer (score 21):

Use these classes for the column.

1. **`d-flex`** to make its display  **`flex`**
2. **`justify-content-center`** to align its content in its center on small screen.
3. **`justify-content-md-start`** to align its content on the left side. Basically it resets the alignment of the element's content from `center` to `left`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
      <img  src="//placehold.it/250" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since the op is talking about bootstrap, it's much better to give a bootstrap solution.